# spring jpa @PreUpdate lost file when called PreUpdate

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, entitylisteners

I have piece entity which contains file(is an byte array),when i will update a recording of piece this last one lost her file:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({ PieceListener.class })
public class Piece extends AbstractAuditingEntity {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPiece;
    @Transient
    @NotNull
    private byte[] file;

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Listener(PieceListener) is:

```
public class PieceListener {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PieceListener.class);
    @PreUpdate
    public void verificationConforme(Piece piece) {
        log.debug("piece id " + piece.getIdPiece);
        log.debug("piece content file " + (piece.getFile()!=null));
        .
        .

    }
@PrePersist
public void changePieceNameAndContentType(Piece piece) {
    log.debug("piece content file " + (piece.getFile()!=null));
}
}
```

And y piece controller is :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PieceResource {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PieceResource.class);

    @PostMapping("/pieces")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Piece> createPiece(@Valid @RequestBody Piece piece) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Piece : {}", piece);
        if (piece.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new piece cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        Piece result = pieceRepository.save(piece);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/pieces/" + result.getId()))
                .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString())).body(result);
    }

    @PutMapping("/pieces")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Piece> updatePiece(@Valid @RequestBody Piece piece) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("piece file is " + (piece.getFile() != null));
        log.debug("REST request to update Piece : {}", piece);
        if (piece.getId() == null) {
            return createPiece(piece);
        }
        log.debug("piece content file is " + (piece.getFile() != null));
        log.debug("piece file is " + piece.getFile());
        Piece result = pieceRepository.save(piece);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(ENTITY_NAME, piece.getId().toString()))
                .body(result);
    }
}
```

in my console I get
piece id idPiece 
but piece content file **false** even if the file isn't null !!.

My question is why file is null,and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Since the field `file` is not persisted, then when you retrieve an object from the database it will have that field as null. But then you don't quote the CODE you use and at what point this is null ...

Comment: but when I try add a new piece :                                        
        `@PrePersist
 public void changePieceNameAndContentType(Piece piece) {
  log.debug("piece content file " + (piece.getFile()!=null));
 }`   i get  piece content file TRUE?